# mp4 video for asterisk with ulaw as audio and h263 for video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, voip, libav, asterisk

Scenario:
I want to play a video file on asterisk. my softphone only support ulaw/h263 for audio and video respectively. So I am allowing both formats in sip.conf file and expecting it to run. asterisk version i am using is 11.7.

I am using mp4_play from app_mp4 to play mp4 hinted files which are converted with mp4creator.

Solution:

What I am trying to do is to create/convert an AV file using ffmpeg to format pcm_mulaw and copying video which is already h263 using command

```
avconv -i input.3gp  -c:a pcm_mulaw  -c:v copy output.mp4
```

I am receiving this error message:

```
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
```

Questions are:

1- Am I moving in the right direction as far as playing a video on asterisk for this particular softphone is concern?

2- is it possible to use ffmpeg in such a manner and content still playable using media players?

3- what other alternative do I have to achieve same task. and how can i avoid this error I am having

Regards

Comment: to make it simple how to have a valid audio/video mp4 file with ulaw audio and h263 video

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying "ffmpeg" when you're using avconv.

Comment: just read your post on the difference I thought the two are same. feeling guilty

Comment: avconv is not ffmpeg

Comment: @user3392156 You shouldn't feel guilty: the `avconv` developers didn't exactly make it easy for users to know the difference. They provided a counterfeit "`ffmpeg`" for a while with a confusing message, and even the name Libav was already and historically used by FFmpeg as a collective name to refer to their libraries (libavcodec, libavformat, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for it and think should be posted as solution is available but not very well spread i guess.

http://downloads.i6net.com/misc/video_tools/debian/ provides number of resources for the same purpose.

- I have used ffmpeg/avconv to convert h264 to h263p

  avconv -i ../big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4 -c:v h263 -vf scale=176:144 -an /tmp/sample-1.3gp
- Added track information in the file using mp4creator

  mp4creator -hint=1 /tmp/sample-1.3gp
- used ffmpeg/avconv to convert audio track to ulaw using

  avconv -y -i ../big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4 -acodec pcm_mulaw -ar 8000 -ac 1 -f mulaw /tmp/convert.mulaw
- and used pcm2mp4 to convert mulaw file obtained above to 3gp. this also add track information for audio track

  pcm2mp4 /tmp/convert.mulaw /tmp/sample-1.3gp

would also like to know why ffmpeg is not providing this conversion.

Comment: Providing what conversion, specifically? You show four commands using three different tools. What do you want `ffmpeg` to do? Also, don't use the term "ffmpeg/avconv". They are not the same and that just causes confusion. For example, you mention "ffmpeg/avconv" but are using avconv, then ask why ffmpeg isn't doing something resulting in me not really following your question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard 
following two things were needed to run file at asterisk that in my knowledge absent in avconv(and also in ffmpeg please correct me if i am wrong)

1) add hint track to mp4/3gp audio/video tracks which was achieved through mp4creator.

2) to add pcm_mulaw audio track to mp4 file which was achieved through pcm2mp4.

also the resultant mp4 file was readable through libmp4v2 which makes me think it is perfectly valid to have ulaw and h263 codecs in one mp4 container contrary to ffmpeg (as you suggested ffmpeg would not do it ) and avconv (as I observed it is not allowing it ).

Comment: currently i am not using ffmpeg. but exploring other online resources makes me think that even ffmpeg would not facilitate such conversion( above two points i mentioned). I would be happy to know If I am wrong.

Comment: also as I mentioned earlier avconv and ffmpeg both provides for adding hint tracks (first of the two requirements) using `-movflags rtphint` but they failed to add a valid payload to hint tracks for reasons I don't know or probably I dont know the correct usage.

Answer (score 1):

## What you can't do

You can't put pcm_mulaw audio or H.263 video in MP4 container.

The error you provided by itself is generally not informative, but it is always accompanied by the actual error (at least for `ffmpeg`, not sure about `avconv`). Probably something this:

```
Could not find tag for codec h263 (or pcm_mulaw) in stream #0,
codec not currently supported in container
```

This is one reason to always include the complete console output when encountering issues.

## What you can do

You can either:

- change the output format container:

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.3gp -c copy output.mkv
  ```
- or re-encode to something acceptable for MP4, such as H.264 video and AAC audio.

  ```
    ffmpeg -i input.3gp -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
  ```

I don't know anything about Asterisk, so I don't know what would be best for you, but this will at least deal with the exact issue you're experiencing.

#### Out with the old

I recommend using a recent build of `ffmpeg`. The `avconv` you are using might be really old, FFmpeg development is very active, and `ffmpeg` has more features. The static builds are easy: just download, extract, and run. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for options for Linux, OS X, and Windows.

Comment: Well I have to be selective for both audio and video codec as to be compatible with Asterisk.

Also want to know if I can't have the two codec in MP4 container is the limitation by ffmpeg or its by MP4 by designed can't have the two together?

Actually I wanted to have a hinted file with the two codec. but avconv failed to produced one with valid payload for me to read. I dont know if its problem with ffmpeg also. I used MP4creator for hinting and it worked.

Comment: @user3392156 I don't know if H.263 and mulaw are specified to be supported by MP4 or not, but `ffmpeg` won't do it, and I've never seen any sample files containing such a combination. I'm not sure what you mean by "hinting" but I assume you want to relocate the `moov` atom to the beginning of the file. You can do with with `ffmpeg` using `-movflags +faststart`.

Comment: video hinting in avconv is added using `-movflags rtphint` but when I used that it doesn't add payload H263 or any